# Tkinter, asksaveasfile, and unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, tkinter

Long story short, I'm making a program that writes a whole bunch of Unicode to a file. It does this by using the Tkinter `asksaveasfile` dialog to let the user choose where they want to save it. Here's the offending snippet (By the way, I imported `tkinter.filedialog` as `fudder` just for fun.):

```
name = fudder.askopenfilename(defaultextension =("Python Files","*.py"),title = "Choose a file to encrypt.")
with open(name,'r') as Usefile:
    filecont = Usefile.read()
    if filecont is None:
        return
    else:
        result = crypt(filecont)
        with fudder.asksaveasfile(mode = 'w', defaultextension = '.txt', title = 'Save the decrypted file.') as newf:
            if result is None:
                return
            else:
                newf.write(result[0].encode('utf-8'))
                newf.write('\n\n\nKey:\n\n\n')
                newf.write(result[1].encode('utf-8'))
                newf.close()
```

I looked at several SO questions like this one, but none of them addressed this in particular. The `asksaveasfile` dialog works just like the `open` function, but I can't specify the encoding. I tried to encode it to bytes, but you can only write strings to a file, and you can't convert the bytes to a string and then convert it back to bytes.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: The `if filecont is None` is bogus. The `read()` method will raise an exception if it cannot read, or return an empty string if there's nothing more to read - it will never return `None`.

Answer (score 6):

I checked the code for `asksaveasfile` and indeed it only passes the filename and mode to open.  It is strictly a convenience function combining a call to `asksaveasfilename` with a call to `open(filename, mode)`, with all other args defaulted.  So don't use it.

Instead, use `asksaveasfilename` and explicitly open the file yourself, just as you did for for the source file.  You can then write the open call you want, with `encoding='utf-8'` and any other non-default options.

The first `with` should end after you have read `Usefile` and have no further need of it.  The `if` statement should therefore be dedented.

Comment: Yes. This is the way to go.

Comment: I was searching a way to save a Pandas Dataframe with Asksaveasfile and with encoding. I guess this answer will help me a lot :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using Python 3 (`tkinter.filedialog` strongly suggests that you are), the file will be opened with the locale encoding as returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding()`. If that is already UTF-8 then you should be able to write directly to the file without explicitly encoding the strings.

However, because you are encrypting the file, `crypt()` probably returns a `bytes` string, not a `str` (unicode) string. If this is the case then you should open the input and output files in *binary* mode. Then no encoding is required when writing to the output file.

```
name = fudder.askopenfilename(defaultextension =("Python Files","*.py"),title = "Choose a file to encrypt.")
with open(name, 'rb') as Usefile:
    filecont = Usefile.read()
    if filecont is None:
        return
    else:
        result = crypt(filecont)
        if result is None:
            return
        with fudder.asksaveasfile(mode = 'wb', defaultextension = '.txt', title = 'Save the decrypted file.') as newf:
            newf.write(result[0])
            newf.write(b'\n\n\nKey:\n\n\n')
            newf.write(result[1])
```

The key differences are:

- Files are opened in binary mode
- No encoding
- Save dialog is not displayed if `crypt()` returns `None`

Comment: @TheRniz So use `newf.write(bytes(result[0], "utf-8"))`

Comment: How do I turn it back into text?